# Sorting an objects using sort from <algorithm>

Tags: c++, sorting, object, vector

I have seen similar questions with responses, and have tried the answers given, for some reason I follow that exact method and my program keeps crashing.

```
    sort(tasks[0], tasks[vTasklist.size() - 1], []( ToDo* a, ToDo* b)
{
    return (a->getPriority() < b->getPriority());
});
```

I have the rest of the full code in the link below if you want to have a look at the rest. Any tips or comments would help.
https://gist.github.com/adamkg3298/26cf7d0ac28155fa499c242e3a4fb565

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: Also, please tag your question with the programming language you're using!

Comment: I am programming in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use iterator of the beginning of that array and end of that array which is :

```
sort(&tasks[0], &tasks[vTasklist.size() - 1], []( ToDo* a, ToDo* b)
{
    return (a->getPriority() < b->getPriority());
});
```

Comment: It's the ampersand I was missing, I see. I appreciate the help abdullah.